# Comboxes - How to activate combo boxes in excel without having to go to " Visual Basic" and running the code

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Each time I run my code I receive duplicate variables. Very annoying, how would I solve this program?

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    With Sheet3.ComboBox2
        .AddItem "TH"
        .AddItem "Reinitialize TH (Moving Along Line)"
        .AddItem "Reinitialize TH (End of Session)"
        .AddItem "Discrepancy W/ Field Notes"
        .AddItem "  "
        .AddItem "Data Collector Failed"
        .AddItem "Mentioned In Field Notes"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Update**

Problem Solved - I was using the wrong function.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change() 
  With Sheet3.ComboBox2 
    ComboBox2.List = Array("TH/Alignment", "Reinitialize TH (Moving Along Line)", "Reinitialize TH (End of Session)", "Discrepancy W/ Field Notes", "Data Collector Failed", "Mentioned In Field Notes", " ")
  End With
End Sub
```

once you run this code, it does not create duplicate values

Comment: `ComboBox2.Clear`

Comment: If i add "ComboBox2.Clear " at the beginning of the code it fixes the duplicates that get generated, BUT, when I select a value, it will not appear in the cell......

Comment: If i add "ComboBox2.Clear " at the end of the code it will create a blank combobox list.

Comment: Why are you adding items to the combobox whenever it changes? that makes no sense.

Comment: Problem Solved - I was using the wrong function.   

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
With Sheet3.ComboBox2
  ComboBox2.List = Array("TH/Alignment", "Reinitialize TH (Moving Along Line)", "Reinitialize TH (End of Session)", "Discrepancy W/ Field Notes", "Data Collector Failed", "Mentioned In Field Notes", " ")
End With
End Sub


'once you run this code, it does not create duplicate values